# Sorting columns within rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table like below

```
id  a   b   c    
1   2   1   3    
2   3   2   1    
3   16  14  15   
4   10  12  13   
5   15  16  14   
6   10  12  8
```

I need to "normalize" this table by sorting values in columns a, b, c - row by row and deduping them counting dups

Expected result

```
a   b   c   dups     
1   2   3   2    
14  15  16  2    
10  12  13  1    
8   10  12  1
```

I do have solution but I don't see how to "scale" it easily to case when I have more than 3 columns to normalize. The first and last column as you can see below is not an issue. Stuff gets messy for columns in the middle when number of columns > 3

```
select a, b, c, count(1) as dups from (
select a1 as a, if(a != a1 and a != c1, a, if(b != a1 and b != c1, b, c)) as b, c1 as c
from (select a, b, c, least(a, b, c) as a1, greatest(a, b, c) as c1 from table)
) group by a, b, c
```

Can anyone suggest another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Below example works for 4 columns and can be adjusted to any number of columns by adding extra STRING(x) to CONCAT() and extra line for REGEXP_EXRACT per each extra column.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, COUNT(1) AS dups 
FROM (
  SELECT id,  
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(s + ',', r'(?U)^(?:.*,){0}(.*),') AS a, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(s + ',', r'(?U)^(?:.*,){1}(.*),') AS b, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(s + ',', r'(?U)^(?:.*,){2}(.*),') AS c, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(s + ',', r'(?U)^(?:.*,){3}(.*),') AS d
  FROM (
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(s) AS s FROM (
      SELECT id, s, 
        INTEGER(s) AS e, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY e) pos
      FROM (
        SELECT id,  
          SPLIT(CONCAT(STRING(a),',',STRING(b),',',STRING(c),',',STRING(d))) AS s 
        FROM table
      ) ORDER BY id, pos
    ) GROUP BY id
  )
) GROUP BY a, b, c, d
```